# Keep rows only if Date exists in both table

Tags: sqlite

This is my first time here, so please bear with me.

Assuming i have 2 table,

Table 1
Date | Closing
1/1/2013 | 1
2/1/2013 | 2

Table 2
Date | Closing
1/1/2013 | 3
3/1/2013 | 4

What sql statements allow me to keep rows such that only Date that exists in both table remains?

End Result:

Table 1
Date | Closing
1/1/2013 | 1

Table 2
Date | Closing
1/1/2013 | 3

Comment: Do you want perform a DELETE action of rows 2/1/2013 of the first table and 3/1/2013 of the second table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to perform a DELETE action:

You'll delete all rows in table1 not present in table2 (by date field) and viceversa

```
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 'X'
    FROM table2
    WHERE table1.date = table2.date
)
```

and

```
DELETE FROM table2
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 'X'
    FROM table1
    WHERE table2.date = table1.date
)
```

If you want to perform a SELECT action

You'll show only rows presents in table1 and table2

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 'X'
    FROM table2
    WHERE table1.date = table2.date
)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 'X'
    FROM table1
    WHERE table2.date = table1.date
)
```